# how to display the value fields in one line but separate

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT bio.nama_lengkap AS nama,bio.jenis_pegawai,bio.progdi,bio.jabatan as jabatan1,bio.cabang,bio.tahun, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user THEN rata_rata END) AS nilai, 
round (avg(rata_rata),2) as rata
    FROM tb_biodata as bio
    INNER JOIN tb_penilaian ON tb_biodata.id_biodata = tb_penilaian.id_biodata
    INNER JOIN tb_user ON tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user 
    WHERE tb_biodata.jenis_pegawai = 'Tenaga Kependidikan' and tb_penilaian.tahun='2020' and tb_biodata.cabang = 'Majapahit 605' GROUP BY nama'
```

[image]

Comment: instead of listing your question as the title of your post please give us some more detail on what you are trying to accomplish, what you are having problems with and what you have tried.

Comment: I want to separate the value fields into three columns but still one line by name

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. You are using `GROUP_CONCAT`. Without that you would have 3 rows per each name where the only difference is the value for the `nilai` column. By using `GROUP_CONCAT` you are collapsing those 3 rows into 1 row and listing the different values in the `nilai` column. You can't break them out into separate columns.

Comment: Here's the documentation on the `GROUP_CONCAT` function for clarification: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: is there a solution but using GROUP_CONCAT but it's still one line

Comment: if what you are asking for is to have 3 `nilai` columns, like `nilai1`, `nilai2` and `nilai3` to list the different values 84.67, 86.67 and 90.00 that is impossible. There is no solution where you can have that be broken out into multiple columns per row with 1 name. Sorry :(

Comment: And a suggestion, please format your code so it is more readable for those trying to help out. If we have to put in a lot of effort to just read your code let alone figure out what you want done and how to do it you probably won't get much help. Here's the link to the information on how to ask a question properly. Please read this before posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak *if what you are asking for is to have 3 nilai columns, like nilai1, nilai2 and nilai3 to list the different values 84.67, 86.67 and 90.00 that is impossible.* ??? why?

Comment: Instead, consider handling issues of data display in application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT  ... ,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user THEN rata_rata END), ',', 1) AS nilai1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user THEN rata_rata END), ',', 2), ',', -1) AS nilai2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user THEN rata_rata END), ',', -1) AS nilai3,
...
```

Alternatively:

```sql
SELECT bio.nama_lengkap AS nama,
       bio.jenis_pegawai,
       bio.progdi,
       bio.jabatan as jabatan1,
       bio.cabang,
       bio.tahun, 
       CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user and numners.num = 1 
            THEN ANY_VALUE(rata_rata) 
            END AS nilai1, 
       CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user and numners.num = 2 
            THEN ANY_VALUE(rata_rata) 
            END AS nilai2, 
       CASE WHEN tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user and numners.num = 3 
            THEN ANY_VALUE(rata_rata) 
            END AS nilai3, 
       round (avg(rata_rata),2) as rata
FROM tb_biodata as bio
INNER JOIN tb_penilaian ON tb_biodata.id_biodata = tb_penilaian.id_biodata
INNER JOIN tb_user ON tb_penilaian.id_user = tb_user.id_user 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) numbers
WHERE tb_biodata.jenis_pegawai = 'Tenaga Kependidikan' 
  and tb_penilaian.tahun='2020' 
  and tb_biodata.cabang = 'Majapahit 605' 
GROUP BY nama'
```